# Does dynamic typing imply dynamic(late binding)?

Tags: javascript, java, c#

AFAIK, all dynamically typed languages use late binding, i.e the name of a method is not binded to a type at compile time. Instead the name of the method is used to look it up at runtime. Can it be possible to use dynamic typing and still use early binding?

Comment: How are c# and Java related to this? They're statically typed.

Comment: They are related because they use early binding.

Comment: You can tag it with every statically typed language then.

Comment: I suppose that cannot be the case because I don't know if every statically typed language uses early binding. For example, it is possible to use late binding with C# with the reflection interface.

Comment: So it is with Java. It has a reflection interface too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. And there is absolutely no reason to use late binding for statically typed methods, because it's sacrificing performance just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Andreas But is it the case with every statically typed language? I don't know that, and that's why I cannot *include every statically typed language*.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes dynamic typing means that binding will occur 'later' at run time, but not vice-versa. You can achieve `late binding` utilizing reflection in strongly typed languages without having any dynamic types. <s>Or even simpler, late binding also happens when runtime resolves the virtual method calls.</s> UPD: this is actually an example of `Dynamic dispatch`, not `Late Binding`, as rightfully noted by @LearningMath.

> Can it be possible to use dynamic typing and still use early binding?

No. That would contradict the definition/meaning of "dynamic typing".

Comment: Using the keyword dynamic is form of late binding or dynamic typing? I don't seem to understand the difference between these two. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @LearningMath I think both. You can use it along with dynamic objects (this is kinda way to relax the C# type system and bring some elements of dynamic typing to it). In .NET those are objects inherited from DynamicObject and capable of doing dynamic binding at run time themselves. On the other hand, you can use `dynamic` keyword with any strongly-typed CLR objects and it will just postpone binding to the run time. You can check some basic info about DLR here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-language-runtime-overview

Comment: So, the former is dynamic typing usage, and the latter dynamic binding only right?

Comment: Isn't the virtual call resolution a dynamic dispatching which is not exactly the same as late binding? The compiler actually has some info about the situation at compile time.